# Security in TYPO3 by accessing File System

Tags: security, typo3

I've readen a book (in german) named `cookbook typo3 and typoscript` http://www.amazon.de/TYPO3-TypoScript-Kochbuch-TYPO3-Programmierung/dp/3446410465

In this book the autor suggest in regards to security that the **typo3_src directory** should be moved out of the root-directory of the web-server, but he didn't say why should we do that?

Can someone explain to me the reason of this suggestion? What vulnerablity would exist if we do not move it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not make public what doesn't need to be.

Not making the directory publicly accessible reduces one possible attack vector.
It might be possible that a file in that directory can be made to do things bad when called directly.

It *is* important to do that if you want to secure your system as much as possible.

Comment: won't be enough to restrict **read/execute access** for the world/others to mitigate this vulnerability?

Comment: No. removing read access for the webserver process user means it cannot use the file at all. execute rights are not checked by php.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is, that you do not need to be able to access typo3_src via the webserver. So do not put things in the public, which do not need to be. If there is a vulnerability via direct access to the source, you would not be vulnerable.

It is just a small stepp. IMHO it is not important and you can ignore it.

Comment: won't be enough to restrict **read/execute access** for the world/others to mitigate this vulnerability?